# Simple Tree Network of Value Chain

Tags: graph, igraph

I'm currently having troubles placing my data frame into a tree plot.

My data-frame looks something like:

```
  sp.    one.     two. three.   four. 
1   a       b       c       d       d   
2   e       f       cc      g       d   
3   h       b       cc      d       d   
4   j       k       cc      l       d   
5   m       n       cc      d       d
```

Could you help me with just the simplest way to incorporate this data frame into a tree network? I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: Okay, what community would you suggest? Is it possible to plot tree networks within igraph?

Comment: How is your network defined? Each row is a path? E.g. is the first row the path `a -> b -> c -> d -> d`?

Comment: Yeah, I defined the path as: a -> b... .etc. the problem is that I don't know how to incorporate the levels from a -> b then from a -> b -> c. My nodes and edges are defined but only from a -> b. I would like to define all the levels to show (in a tree diagram) how my network is connected (in my example on 5 levels... i.e. sp. -> four).

Comment: Would be nice to see what output you want, because this graph is not a tree, so I am not sure what you mean by "tree diagram".

Comment: I'm aiming for an output such as the one labeled "Tree" in this blog: http://horicky.blogspot.de/2012/04/basic-graph-analytics-using-igraph.html

Comment: I should probably just use then, two columns and two rows. Then classify my paths from this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really plot it as a tree, because it is not a tree. If you really want a tree shape, then you can calculate a minimum spanning tree, calculate the tree layout on that and then use these coordinates with the original graph.

Here we just plot it with a general layout.

```
dftext <- "  sp.    one.     two. three.   four.
          1   a       b       c       d       d
          2   e       f       cc      g       d
          3   h       b       cc      d       d
          4   j       k       cc      l       d
          5   m       n       cc      d       d
"
df <- read.table(text=dftext, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(igraph)
vert <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))
g <- graph.empty(n=length(vert))
V(g)$name <- vert
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    g <- g + path(as.character(df[i,]))
}

lay <- layout.reingold.tilford(simplify(g), root="d")
plot(g, layout=lay)
```

[image: plot]